# Responsive Header,doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive header that when the screen size is smaller than 992 a hamburger menu appears that controls the menu using a checkbox.
The problem I'm trying to solve is the menu not showing even if the checkbox is checked.

What I have so far is below.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@400;700&family=Roboto&display=swap");
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {

    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fcddc6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

.header:not(.menu) {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-image {
    margin: 15px;
}

.header-middle ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header-middle ul a {
    color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.header-middle ul a li {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#header-right-links {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.hamburger,
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
    content: "";
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.hamburger::before {
    top: -10px;
    width: 20px;
}

.hamburger::after {
    top: 10px;
    width: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    top: 34px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger {
    background: transparent;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger:before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 30px;
}

.header .menu-toggle:checked+.header-middle,
.menu-toggle:checked~.menu,
.menu-toggle:checked+.header-right {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}


@media (max-width:992px) {

    .menu-toggle,
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    .header-middle,
    .header-right {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: start;
        position: fixed;
        top: 85px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 800px;
        right: -300px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        background-color: #dc9a7f;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #dc9a7f;
        border-style: solid;


    }

    .menu {

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: start;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .header-middle li {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .menu a {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-width: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 245, .5) inset;
    }

    .header-middle ul li:hover {
        color: white;
    }

    .header-right {
        background: transparent;
        height: auto;
        top: 455px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d92fc73161.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
        <a class="logo-link" href="https://www.example.com/"><img class="logo-image" src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="header-middle">
            <ul class="menu">
                <a href="https://www.example.com/">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.example.com/">
                    <li>Products</li>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.example.com/">
                    <li>About Us</li>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.example.com/">
                    <li>Contact Us</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
        <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
        <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
</div>
```

I'm struggling to find a solution, and I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your HTML to be able to select your ul using CSS selector (~) when checkbox is checked. I changed also position for ul as absolute to give it a top and right position. I also used overflow: hidden; not to have the x scrollbar. Fontawsome icons were display : none with small screen (you can try placing it wherever you want using the same procedure).

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@400;700&family=Roboto&display=swap");
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {

    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fcddc6;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}


.header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-image {
    margin: 15px;
}

ul.ul-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.header ul a li {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#header-right-links {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.hamburger,
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
    content: "";
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.hamburger::before {
    top: -10px;
    width: 20px;
}

.hamburger::after {
    top: 10px;
    width: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    top: 0px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger {
    background: transparent;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger:before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 30px;
}


@media (max-width:992px) {


    .menu-toggle:checked~ul.ul-menu{ /*select every ul that is preceded by a checked .menu-toggle*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 50%;
        transform: translate(50%);  /* this to properly center the ul menu try comment it to see*/
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        transition: all 500ms ease;

    }

    .header-right{
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-toggle,
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    ul.ul-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -200px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .ul-menu a {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-width: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 245, .5) inset;
    }

    .header ul li:hover {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d92fc73161.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
        <a class="logo-link" href="https://www.example.com/"><img class="logo-image" src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="hamburger"></div>
    <ul class="ul-menu">
        <a href="https://www.example.com/">
            <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/">
            <li>Products</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/">
            <li>About Us</li>
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.example.com/">
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
    <div class="header-right">
        <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
        <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
        <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mehdi, Thankyou very much, I really appreciate you for helping me.

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad that it helped. If so you can also upvote or accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

Error is due to Positioning and z-index of the elements in your CSS

```
.header-middle,
.header-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    position: fixed;
    top: 85px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 800px;
    right: -300px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-color: #dc9a7f;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #dc9a7f;
    border-style: solid;
    z-index: 10; 
    transition: right 0.3s ease; 


}

.menu {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: start;
    position: fixed;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    transform: translateX(100%); 
    z-index: 5; 
}

.header-middle li {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 245, .5) inset;
}

.header-middle ul li:hover {
    color: white;
}

.header-right {
    background: transparent;
    height: auto;
    top: 455px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

}

Try this...it might help

Comment: it didn't help sadly, it's same like before

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to keep your input after the ul, now with :has() you can also select a sibling that comes before by using this ".header:has(:checked) > ul.ul-menu". See the code below.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@400;700&family=Roboto&display=swap");
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {

    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fcddc6;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;


}


.header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-image {
    margin: 15px;
}

ul.ul-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
    justify-content: space-between;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    gap: 2rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.header ul a li {
    font-family: 'Comfortaa';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#header-right-links {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.hamburger,
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

.hamburger {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
    content: "";
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 4px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(42, 19, 19, 1);
    transition: .3s ease;
}

.hamburger::before {
    top: -10px;
    width: 20px;
}

.hamburger::after {
    top: 10px;
    width: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle {
    top: 0px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger {
    background: transparent;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger:before {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 30px;
}

.menu-toggle:checked+.hamburger:after {
    top: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    width: 30px;
}


@media (max-width:992px) {


    .header:has(:checked) > ul.ul-menu{ /* now with :has() you can also select a sibling that comes before*/
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 50%;
        transform: translate(50%);  /* this to properly center the ul menu try comment it to see*/
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        transition: all 500ms ease;

    }

    .header-right{
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-toggle,
    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    ul.ul-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -200px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .ul-menu a {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 25px;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-width: 1px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 245, .5) inset;
    }

    .header ul li:hover {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d92fc73161.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="header-left">
          <a class="logo-link" href="https://www.example.com/"><img class="logo-image" src="https://picsum.photos/30/30" alt="" /></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="ul-menu">
          <a href="https://www.example.com/">
              <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/">
              <li>Products</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/">
              <li>About Us</li>
          </a>
          <a href="https://www.example.com/">
              <li>Contact Us</li>
          </a>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-right">
          <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
          <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-regular fa-heart"></i>
          <i id="header-right-links" class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
  </div>
```